# How to change the multilevel columns and pandas and plot them?

Tags: python, pandas

I was going through a pandas manipulation code and stuck how to swap the column indices.

## MWE

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(100)
n = 500

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'airport':np.random.choice(['A','B','C'],size=n),
     'fare':np.random.randint(1,100,size=n),
     'trip':np.random.randint(1,100,size=n),
     'day':np.random.choice(range(6),size=n)

     })
```

## What I did

```py
df1 = df.groupby(['day','airport'])[['fare','trip']].mean().unstack()
df1.plot(subplots=True)
print(df1)
```

## Required

- One plot of layout (1,3)
- ax00 is for airport A: x = day and y has two line plots for fare and trip.
- ax01 is for airport B: x = day and y has two line plots for fare and trip.
- ax02 is for airport C: x = day and y has two line plots for fare and trip.

The first plot should look like:

```py
df00 = df.query("airport == 'A'")
df00.groupby('day')[['fare','trip']].mean().plot()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojnDv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to analyse the relation between the average `fair` and `trip` of various airports at different days, in such scenarios we can use `relplot` from seaborn package which provides convinient way of drawing the relational plots

```
import seaborn as sns

df1 = df.groupby(['day', 'airport']).mean().stack().reset_index(name='val')
sns.relplot(x='day', y='val', hue='level_2', kind='line', col='airport', data=df1, col_wrap=3)
```

---

[image]